# Error Drupal 7 body content missing when adding new content

Tags: views

Hi my drupal 7 creating a new content, suddenly the body field disappear? and i dont know what cause this? is there anyone can help me

Answer (score 1):

The body field is field attached to content type, so if its remove from particular content type, then it mean you have removed the fields from the content type.

You can enable the fields again for the content type by Administrator -> Structure -> Content type -> [type] ->Manage fields.

In the section "Add existing field", you can select the fields "body" and add to content type.
[image: Adding body field to content type]